# "ssh-copy-id user@ip_address" throws error

Tags: server, ssh, 22.04, openssh, remote-login

In UBUNTU system, I'm trying to set up remote login system. It is failing in ssh-copy-id step. It throws the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XX.XXX port 22: Connection refused
```

Trying ssh XXX.XXX.XX.XXX gives-

```
The authenticity of host 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XX.XXX)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:*********.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? ssh user@XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint:
```

What can I do? Thanks in advance.
N.B. I tried the steps several times following different tutorials and while starting afresh each time, I just removed the files under /.ssh folder.

Comment: Is 192.168.59.253 the correct IP? Does that machine have a running ssh daemon listening for connections on port 22? Can you run `ssh 192.168.59.253`? What happens? Do you log in? Please ***[edit]*** your question and add this information.

Comment: @terdon I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Did you try typing yes at the prompt?

Comment: Yes. It then seems like I am connected to the host. But this doesn't work for remote computers. It happens only when I run the command from the host.

Comment: Sorry, what? What host? Why are you mentioning the host now? Please tell us i) what happens when you `ssh 192.168.59.253` (these are local IPs, of your local network, and not accessible from outside the network, there is no reason to hide the IP) and ii) assuming you get the prompt you show, and write `yes` to connect, what happens if you try `ssh-copy-id` AFTER connecting manually once, and disconnecting.

Comment: Doing ii) I get known_hosts file in .ssh directory. If I run ssh-copy-id then `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys` and then asks for password. Typing password got `Number of key(s) added: 1
Now try logging with: "ssh 'cblast@192.168.59.253'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.`

Comment: @terdon ` Then I tried to login with ssh which gives me `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/cblast/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation` and asks for password. I checked .ssh directory again and there were newly added `ssh-copy-id.DJSnecrASz` and `authorized_keys` files.

Comment: OK, please add all this to the question.